# Can you not use AND in n1ql queries?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

SELECT variable FROM `bucket` WHERE type = 'type1' AND distance(in the documents with typ1)= distance(from another document with a type). How would I write a query that satisfies that?

Answer (score 0):

N1QL supports AND, OR, and complex predicates. Btw, what is distance() function? I don't recall if that exists in N1QL.
Can you post the exact query you are trying to run.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a sql restful service to couchbase. sql query looks like "SELECT ULDSerial FROM BeaconLink WHERE BeaconSerial = \'" + variable+ "\'" . variable is variable in the method that will be compared. ULDSerial  and BeaconSerial are rows in the table.

In my cocuchbase app, I have one bucket where all the document are being stored. My N1QL looks like: "SELECT `bucket`.uldNumber FROM `bucket` WHERE type = 'BeaconLink' AND SerialNumber = \'" + variable+ "\'"; 

They query before the WHERE statement works.

Comment: The query with the and statement is as follows:                "SELECT `bucket`.distance FROM `bucket` WHERE type = 'UT_BEACON_INFO' AND ReceivedDate>= \'" + currentDate.AddSeconds(-5) + "\' AND receivedDate <= \'" + currentDate.AddSeconds(5) + "\' AND serialNumber = \'" + serialNumber + "\' AND receiverId = \'" + receiverId + "\'"
sql query that works: "SELECT Distance FROM UT_BEACON_INFO WHERE ReceivedDate >= \'" + currentDate.AddSeconds(-5) + "\' AND ReceivedDate <= \'" + currentDate.AddSeconds(5) + "\' AND SerialNumber = \'" + serialNumber + "\' AND ReceiverId = \'" + receiverId + "\'"

Comment: If you could take a look at my two comments above

Comment: @lamasking88 : edit your question instead of comment this reply